# Am I abusing stubbing in my unit tests?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, stubbing

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application and I have a `BillingPlan` model containing the following methods:

```
class BillingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def billing_months
    dates = [Date.new(Date.today.year, start_month.value, billing_day)]

    while dates.size < billings_in_year
      dates << dates.last + recurrence.value.months
    end

    dates.map{ |d| d.month }
  end

  def billings_in_year
    12 / recurrence.value
  end
end
```

To test the code, I've written the following spec:

```
describe BillingPlan do
  # ...

  describe '#billings_in_year' do
    subject do
      (plan = BillingPlan.new).stubs(
        recurrence: stub(value: 4)
      ) && plan
    end

    it 'returns the number of billings in a year' do
      expect(subject.billings_in_year).to eq(3)
    end
  end

  describe '#billing_months' do
    subject do
      (plan = BillingPlan.new).stubs(
        recurrence: stub(value: 2),
        start_month: stub(value: 2),
        billings_in_year: 6,
        billing_day: 21
      ) && plan
    end

    it 'returns the months when billing is done' do
      expect(subject.billing_months).to eq([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12])
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, I have managed to completely isolate the two methods by using Mocha. However, I'm wondering whether I'm *abusing* stubs in my test? Isn't it too dependent on the methods' inner workings? Can you provide a general rule to know how extensively one should rely on mocking/faking?

Note: `recurrence` and `start_month` are objects of a third-party class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests stub what they need to to isolate the cases they test, but they do hint at a problem your methods have - they don't obey the [Law of Demeter](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/):

> - You can play with yourself.
> - You can play with your own toys (but you can’t take them apart),
> - You can play with toys that were given to you.
> - And you can play with toys you’ve made yourself.

Every place you need to stub a value of a stub - you have a problem.

> Assuming this is a Rails program, it is extremely easy to change the
>   code to satisfy the law. First, we make a one-line addition to the
>   User class:
>
> ```
> class User
>   delegate :name, :to => :department, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
>   # ...
> end
> ```

If this solution, for some reason is not viable, you can use this solution:

> Demeter doesn’t prevent us from interacting with an objects second-
>   and third-order associations; it simply asserts that we can’t interact
>   with all of those objects in the same method. Look again at the
>   formulation of the law:
>
> > *…all objects to which M sends a message…*
>
> Demeter is a rule about methods only; it does not limit the set of
>   types a class can interact with.
>
> So this is perfectly legal:
>
> ```
> class StatPresenter
>   def human_stats(human)
>     "Age: #{human.age}.nCountry stats:n#{country_stats(human.country)}"
>   end
>
>   def country_stats(country)
>     "  Mortality rate: #{country.mortality_rate}"
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: In this specific case I was able to use `recurrence_value` and `start_month_value`, which are aliases added automatically. Thanks a lot for reminding me of Demeter's Law: I remember reading about it some time ago, but I've never followed it until now.